# Moving an instance from superclass to subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, methods

I'm making a a program that builds users (I'm currently learning classes). And I can create two types of users: User and Admin.

Both User and Admin can have their first and last names, age and **privileges**. Admin is a subclass from superclass and has more privileges than normal User.

What I want to do is to make a normal User an Admin, basically move and instance created from class User to class Admin.

I looked for this kind of problem, but I couldn't find it.

```
    """docstring for User"""
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, location):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
        self.location = location
        self.privileges = [
            'can add post', 'can remove their post', 'can change their icon'
            ]

    def describe_user(self):
        print(f"First name: {self.first_name}")
        print(f"Last name: {self.last_name}")
        print(f"Age: {self.age}")
        print(f"Location: {self.location}")

    def greet_user(self):
        print(f"Hello, {self.first_name} {self.last_name}, good to see you!")

    def show_privileges(self):
        print("Privileges:")
        for privilege in self.privileges:
            print(f"- {privilege}")

class Admin(User):
    """docstring for Admin"""
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age, location):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, age, location)
        self.privileges = [
            'can add post', 'can remove post', 'can ban user', 'can lock post'
            ]
    def show_privileges(self):
        print("Privileges:")
        for privilege in self.privileges:
            print(f"- {privilege}")


kaya = User('Kaya', 'Y', 20, 'Chicago')
jon = Admin('Jon', 'K', 17, 'NY')

jon.greet_user()
jon.describe_user()

jon.show_privileges()
print('\n')

kaya.greet_user()
kaya.describe_user()

kaya.show_privileges()
```

How would I go about making kaya an Admin?

EDIT_0: I want to move an instance, not a method.

EDIT_1: I would like to add something like

```
kaya.make_admin()
```

which would give the instance kaya some more privileges.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to make a "clone" of `kaya` with all the same properties of the original except that it is an Admin, and replace the object in `kaya` with the Admin clone?

Comment: That's what `jon` is. But what if I have many normal users and I decide to make one of them an Admin without manually moving them to the Admin class?

Comment: `kaya = kaya.make_admin()` would be trivial, just return a new `Admin` inside `User.make_admin()`

Comment: That's what I want, but I don't know how to do it!

Comment: `def make_admin(): return Admin(self.first_name , etc, etc)` ?

Comment: Thanks, solved it!. That does exactly what I want, in the end I had to user `kaya = kaya.make_admin()` because I'm returning an `Admin`.

Comment: @armin84 I think inheritance not a great design though. You probably want a `User` class that has a `Permissions` object. Then an admin is just a `User` but with the `AdminPermissions`. This way you don't morph the type of kaya, you just give it the right permissions to be an admin.

Comment: The chapter is actually on inheritance  so I had to use it, it's my first time actually! Oh that actually makes some sense design-wise, it would be easier to read and easier to modify. But later, what if I want to add another attribute to an admin? I would need to make another method inside of `User`, which would make the code longer and much harder to read.

Considering this case, isn't it better to use inheritance?